# Please recommend some good hosting for Facebook App (free/paid)

Tags: web-hosting, facebook, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I am learning to program facebook app and so I am looking for some free/trial/paid hosting
to host my php and db.

Comment: agree with mogu... Don't need to spend money in vain, best to program it locally and make it EASY to migrate, meaning use variables to ABSOLUTE POSITION any urls, espically if you're planning to use url rewrites. WAMP Server is great @ wampserver.com

Comment: Answers should bear in mind that from October https will be necessary for FB apps, so shared hosting is unlikely to cut it.

Answer (score 1):

i am using hostgator and it is running perfectlu so far.

just in case of need, you can use the coupon code "hostgatorBestOffer" which will save u save money.

Answer (score 1):

localhost (your machine) for starter is good idea, all you need static ip.
once you finished you app go straight to aws.amazon.com

Comment: static ip is for asking feedback from friends while you design&develop. otherwise dynamic ip is ok as well